# Доступ из UserControl к ViewModel окна

Tags: avalonia

Есть главное окно в котором есть
`<Image IsVisible="{Binding pod_poj,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="pod_pojo"/>`
которое управляется через ViewModel из кода этого окна . К окну подключен UserControl . Вот как бы из кода UserControl поуправлять моделью главного окна ? ну или напрямую иконкой ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим образом . В главном окне , а это у меня меню , DataContext я присвоил ViewModel с pod_poj которую создал как глобальную . В UserControl или любом другом окне текущего модуля эта ViewModel является доступной . Для окон в подключаемых библиотек стандартный путь через параметры . Вопрос снят .